# LLVM | How to implement IR code generation of Logical Not operations

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, llvm, llvm-ir

Suppose I have a function like this:

```
// global variables
llvm::LLVMContext* context;
llvm::Module* module;
llvm::IRBuilder<>* builder;

Value* logical_not_codegen(Value* operand) {
    return builder->CreateLogicalNotOp(operand);
}
```

According to the docs, there is no function like `CreateLogicalNotOp` in `IRBuilder`, so my question is:

Is there anything from `IRBuilder` I can use to generate IR code for a logical not operation?

EDIT: BTW I think `builder.CreateNot()` is binary not, am I correct?

Comment: Can't you use `CreateNot` for this? It's a binary not, but I assume it would be correct on a boolean value.

Comment: @Hasturkun I think `CreateNot` is binary not. Because the generated IR code for `~3` (my binary not is implemented using `CreateNot`), the generated constant value is `-4`, which is exactly the binary not-ed `3`

Comment: If the value was in an `i1`, I think it would be equivalent. You can probably get there by generating a compare against 0. I haven't really dealt with LLVM much though.

Comment: Xor against constant -1 should do.

Comment: @Hasturkun thx I'll try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BTW this is how you do it:

```
  auto size_in_bits = rhs->getType()->getPrimitiveSizeInBits();
  if (rhs->getType()->isFloatingPointTy()) {
    return _builder->CreateFCmpOEQ(rhs, ConstantFP::get(_builder->getFloatTy(), 0.0f));
  } else if (rhs->getType()->isSingleValueType()) {
    return _builder->CreateICmpEQ(rhs, ConstantInt::get(_builder->getIntNTy((unsigned)size_in_bits), 0, false));
  }
```